# Append element in ng-repeat cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array of objects, every objects have parametr with date, so I want to past a date between elements in `ng-repeat`. For this I write a directive and append date before elements.
.after in code works fine, but `.before`, or `elem.parent().append("date is here")` is not working. Where I'm wrong, why element isn't appends before element of `ng-repeat`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="doc in array" divider>
      {{doc.name}}
    </div>
    <script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.array = [{
        name: 'Document from John Doe',
        date: "2017-05-30T11:05:59.118+0300"
      },{
        name: "Document from Lisa Ginx",
        date: "2017-05-24T13:51:09.736+0300"
      },{
        name: "Document from Crazy Kid",
        date: "2017-05-24T13:51:09.736+0300"
      }, {
        name: "Untitled Document",
        date: "2017-05-18T13:51:09.736+0300"
      }]
    })
    .directive('divider', [
      function() {
        return {
          link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
          var dates = {'1': 'January', '2': 'February', '3': 'March', '4': 'April', '5': 'May', '6': 'June', '7':'July', '8':'August', '9': 'September', '10': 'October', '11': 'November', '12': 'December'}  
          var next = scope.$index + 1,
              prevMonth = scope.array[next] ? new Date(scope.array[next].date).getMonth() + 1 : null,
              prevDay = scope.array[next] ? new Date(scope.array[next].date).getDate() : null;
          
          var current = scope.$index,
              currentMonth = new Date(scope.array[current].date).getMonth() + 1,
              currentDay = new Date(scope.array[current].date).getDate();
              
      if( prevDay !== currentDay )
        angular.element(elem).after('<div style="font-style:italic">--'+ dates[currentMonth] + " " + currentDay  +'--</div>');
            // angular.element(elem).before('<div style="font-style:italic">--'+ dates[currentMonth] + " " + currentDay  +'--</div>');
            // elem.parent().append('<div style="font-style:italic">--'+ dates[currentMonth] + " " + currentDay  +'--</div>')            
          }
        };
      }
    ]);
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was trying this way, but it's very bad.. https://plnkr.co/edit/rtoZP72L1ErRK9qxq2KV?p=preview